# Android: Unable to execute HTTP request Unable to resolve host

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I am trying to connect to DynamoDb through Cognito using the code that Amazon provides. All I change are the app specific parameters.

When I execute the code I get the following exception:
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname.

What does this exception want from me? I would assume that the list of hosts is internal to Amazon libraries.

thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve host: URL No address associated with hostname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766705/unable-to-resolve-host-url-no-address-associated-with-hostname)

Comment: are you connected to internet? Wifi ? 3G?

Comment: yes, I am connected to the internet on my computer and I am typing this response :). I am actually using the emulator. and Btw, this is not a duplicate of that error. there *is* an address associated with the request, it just doesn't work.

Comment: The reason why this is not a duplicate of the other question is because, as I mentioned, I am using Amazon code which wraps all of the details of the call. It is a sample they provide -- and by now I doubt that it has ever worked for anybody :(

Comment: The endpoint is an official as listed here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region. I suspect it's network issue. Would you please check your network?